# pragma omp parallel for does not speed up my program

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have tried adding #pragma parallel omp for to this raytracing program and am measuring the same/very similar amount of processing time with and without the pragma statement.

This is the function:

```
 void Scene::SaveImage(
        const char *outPngFileName, 
        int pixelsWide, 
        int pixelsHigh, 
        double zoom, 
        int antiAliasFactor) const
    {
        // Oversample the image using the anti-aliasing factor.

        const int largePixelsWide = antiAliasFactor * pixelsWide;
        const int largePixelsHigh = antiAliasFactor * pixelsHigh;
        const int smallerDim = 
            ((pixelsWide < pixelsHigh) ? pixelsWide : pixelsHigh);

        const double largeZoom  = antiAliasFactor * zoom * smallerDim;
        ImageBuffer buffer(largePixelsWide, largePixelsHigh, backgroundColor);

        // The camera is located at the origin.
        Vector camera(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

        // The camera faces in the -z direction.
        // This allows the +x direction to be to the right,
        // and the +y direction to be upward.
        Vector direction(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);

        const Color fullIntensity(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

        // We keep a list of (i,j) screen coordinates for pixels
        // we are not able to trace definitive rays for.
        // Later we will come back and fix these pixels.
        PixelList ambiguousPixelList;

        #pragma omp parallel for 
        for (int i=0; i < largePixelsWide; ++i)
        {
            direction.x = (i - largePixelsWide/2.0) / largeZoom;
            for (int j = 0; j < largePixelsHigh; ++j)
            {
                direction.y = (largePixelsHigh / 2.0 - j) / largeZoom;


#if RAYTRACE_DEBUG_POINTS
                {
                    using namespace std;

                    // Assume no active debug point unless we find one below.
                    activeDebugPoint = NULL;    

                    DebugPointList::const_iterator iter = debugPointList.begin();
                    DebugPointList::const_iterator end  = debugPointList.end();
                    for(; iter != end; ++iter)
                    {
                        if ((iter->iPixel == i) && (iter->jPixel == j))
                        {
                            cout << endl;
                            cout << "Hit breakpoint at (";
                            cout << i << ", " << j <<")" << endl;
                            activeDebugPoint = &(*iter);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
#endif

                PixelData& pixel = buffer.Pixel(i,j);
                try
                {
                    // Trace a ray from the camera toward the given direction
                    // to figure out what color to assign to this pixel.
                    pixel.color = TraceRay(
                        camera,
                        direction,
                        ambientRefraction,
                        fullIntensity,
                        0);
                }
                catch (AmbiguousIntersectionException)
                {
                    // Getting here means that somewhere in the recursive 
                    // code for tracing rays, there were multiple 
                    // intersections that had minimum distance from a 
                    // vantage point.  This can be really bad, 
                    // for example causing a ray of light to reflect 
                    // inward into a solid.

                    // Mark the pixel as ambiguous, so that any other
                    // ambiguous pixels nearby know not to use it.
                    pixel.isAmbiguous = true;

                    // Keep a list of all ambiguous pixel coordinates
                    // so that we can rapidly enumerate through them
                    // in the disambiguation pass.
                    ambiguousPixelList.push_back(PixelCoordinates(i, j));
                }
            }
        }

#if RAYTRACE_DEBUG_POINTS
        // Leave no chance of a dangling pointer into debug points.
        activeDebugPoint = NULL;
#endif

        // Go back and "heal" ambiguous pixels as best we can.
        PixelList::const_iterator iter = ambiguousPixelList.begin();
        PixelList::const_iterator end  = ambiguousPixelList.end();
        for (; iter != end; ++iter)
        {
            const PixelCoordinates& p = *iter;
            ResolveAmbiguousPixel(buffer, p.i, p.j);
        }

        // We want to scale the arbitrary range of
        // color component values to the range 0..255
        // allowed by PNG format.  We therefore find
        // the maximum red, green, or blue value anywhere
        // in the image.
        const double max = buffer.MaxColorValue();

        // Downsample the image buffer to an integer array of RGBA 
        // values that LodePNG understands.
        const unsigned char OPAQUE_ALPHA_VALUE = 255;
        const unsigned BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 4;

        // The number of bytes in buffer to be passed to LodePNG.
        const unsigned RGBA_BUFFER_SIZE = 
            pixelsWide * pixelsHigh * BYTES_PER_PIXEL;

        std::vector<unsigned char> rgbaBuffer(RGBA_BUFFER_SIZE);
        unsigned rgbaIndex = 0;
        const double patchSize = antiAliasFactor * antiAliasFactor;
        //#pragma parallel for collapse(3)
        for (int j=0; j < pixelsHigh; ++j)
        {
            for (int i=0; i < pixelsWide; ++i)
            {
                Color sum(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                for (int di=0; di < antiAliasFactor; ++di)
                {
                    //#pragma parallel omp for reduction(+:sum)
                    for (int dj=0; dj < antiAliasFactor; ++dj)
                    {
                        sum += buffer.Pixel(
                            antiAliasFactor*i + di, 
                            antiAliasFactor*j + dj).color;
                    }
                }
                sum /= patchSize;

                // Convert to integer red, green, blue, alpha values,
                // all of which must be in the range 0..255.
                rgbaBuffer[rgbaIndex++] = ConvertPixelValue(sum.red,   max);
                rgbaBuffer[rgbaIndex++] = ConvertPixelValue(sum.green, max);
                rgbaBuffer[rgbaIndex++] = ConvertPixelValue(sum.blue,  max);
                rgbaBuffer[rgbaIndex++] = OPAQUE_ALPHA_VALUE;
            }
        }

        // Write the PNG file
        const unsigned error = lodepng::encode(
            outPngFileName, 
            rgbaBuffer, 
            pixelsWide, 
            pixelsHigh);

        // If there was an encoding error, throw an exception.
        if (error != 0)
        {
            std::string message = "PNG encoder error: ";
            message += lodepng_error_text(error);
            throw ImagerException(message.c_str());
        }

    }

    // The following function searches through all solid objects
    // for the first solid (if any) that contains the given point.
    // In the case of ties, the solid that was inserted into the
    // scene first wins.  This arbitrary convention allows the
    // composer of a scene to decide which of multiple overlapping
    // objects should control the index of refraction for any
    // overlapping volumes of space.
    const SolidObject* Scene::PrimaryContainer(const Vector& point) const
    {
        SolidObjectList::const_iterator iter = solidObjectList.begin();
        SolidObjectList::const_iterator end  = solidObjectList.end();
        for (; iter != end; ++iter)
        {
            const SolidObject* solid = *iter;
            if (solid->Contains(point))
            {
                return solid;
            }
        }

        return NULL;
    }
```

This is the snippet I added it to:

```
        #pragma omp parallel for 
        for (int i=0; i < largePixelsWide; ++i)
        {
            direction.x = (i - largePixelsWide/2.0) / largeZoom;
            for (int j = 0; j < largePixelsHigh; ++j)
            {
                direction.y = (largePixelsHigh / 2.0 - j) / largeZoom;
```

I have made sure all of my VS17 settings are correct and -fopenmp main.cpp is on command arguments. Additional information: This is in another file called scene.cpp, omp header file is added to scene.cpp.

My questions are how can I get this to work and if there are other parts where I can add it where/how would I go about doing it. Thank you.

Comment: Two things. First, be aware that `#pragma parallel omp` does not guarantee a change in execution time. So technically, you have not demonstrated a problem with this code. Second, could you try moving the declaration of `direction` inside the outer loop (the `i` loop)?

Comment: I'm afraid that your code is full of race conditions. You are sharing many variables between threads that should not be shared. (For example, consider what happens to "direction", when many iterations of the outer "i" loop are executing simultaneously! Another obvious race is on rgbaindex). If this is giving the correct results, then I think you're not compiling with OpenMP enabled, which would explain the parity of performance...